# wxPython and matplotlib.widgets

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I'm working on a Python app that uses wxPython for a GUI with an embedded matplotlib figure. It was going really well until I tried to use a matplotlib [GUI-neutral widget](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.SpanSelector) called a `SpanSelector`. Before, I was trying to code this behavior myself, which wasn't going very well, so I was pleased that there was a built-in widget that would take care of it for me. These widgets are supposed to work with any GUI backend, and wxPython is definitely a supported backend.

My code is pretty simple at the moment; I have a defined application class with these (relevant) functions:

```
def init_gui(self):
    ...
    self.button5 = wx.Button(tab, label="Manual select", size=(120, 30))
    self.button5.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.get_selection_manual)
    ...

def get_selection_manual(self, event):
    span = matplotlib.widgets.SpanSelector(self.ax, \
        self.process_selection_manual, "horizontal", useblit=True, \
        rectprops=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor="red"))

def process_selection_manual(self, vmin, vmax):
    print vmin, vmax
```

If it was working, all it should do is print out the selection the user made after clicking the button. I know that `get_selection_manual` is called, but clicking and dragging over the plot never creates a selection, and the callback `process_selection_manual` is never called.

I tried putting in a `sleep()` and then updating the display. Interestingly, I got it to (sort of) work when my application crashed over a `sleep(5)` instead of a `time.sleep(5)`. So Python was stalled, but it drew the selection like it was supposed to then. I've never seen that happen before, and I'm not really sure what it means. I haven't found any examples of using wxPython and matplotlib widgets together, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a really simple solution: `span` has to be declared `self.span`... Maybe it was getting garbage-collected before it could do anything? In any case, it works now if I replace

```
def get_selection_manual(self, event):
    span = matplotlib.widgets.SpanSelector(self.ax, \
        self.process_selection_manual, "horizontal", useblit=True, \
        rectprops=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor="red"))
```

with

```
def get_selection_manual(self, event):
    self.span = matplotlib.widgets.SpanSelector(self.ax, \
        self.process_selection_manual, "horizontal", \
        rectprops=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor="red"))
```

I also removed the `useblit` flag because it messed up the color; I don't think it was relevant to this fix, but still useful to note.

Comment: That would most likely do it; getting erased upon exiting function scope would probably be hazardous to its health.